# Not able to create a localhost connection for hr table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to oracle sql developer, I installed Oracle Database 12c Release 2, to my computer, and I created oracleTest "sys as sysdba", and I unlocked hr user by using "ALTER USER HR IDENTIFIED BY hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;" and I verified it is unlocked. 
[image: sysdba connection image]

[image: hr verification, as shown it is unlocked image]

Now I am trying to create a new localhost connection so that I can only see hr tables, but when I entered all info it says "Invalid username/password". I used hr as password first and then I used the sys password, but it still gives the same error. Can anyone please help.

[image: Error image]

[image: sqlplus output]

I created new sysconnection, this is how it looks like

[image: new sys sql developer connection]

Comment: Did you pay attention to letter case? Passwords are case sensitive (by default).

Comment: Yes, I've been trying this for 2 days, and googled a lot, but couldn't find any solution

Comment: What is the result of this (ran as SYS or SYSTEM): `select account_status, lock_date, expiry_date from dba_users where username = 'HR';`

Comment: l used sql plus, entered username sys as sysdba, and after connecting to sql I entered select account_status, lock_date, expiry_date from dba_users where username = 'HR'; it says 'no rows selected'

Comment: It means that there's no HR user in your database. Verify that by running `select * from all_users;`

Comment: I had it before and made a mistake deleted the oracleTest and created again and when I run select * from all_users; I don't see hr now

Comment: If it isn't there, then it is dropped.

Comment: Okay, I see hr user now

Comment: How come (if it wasn't here)?

Comment: I created a sys connection again, but still not able to create hr localhost connection, it gives the same error

Comment: Huh, that just doesn't make sense to me ... users don't *automagically* appear and disappear and - if they are here, unlocked, with a known password - I don't know why would creating a connection complain about invalid username/password. You're probably doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I wish I could add more picture to here

Comment: Can you connect via SQL*Plus? As `connect hr/hr`?

Comment: No, it gives the same error; SQL> connect hr/hr
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, run the following statements in your database and copy/paste SQL*Plus output to the initial question you asked; don't post it as a comment.

```
SQL> connect system
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select account_status, lock_date, expiry_date from dba_users where username = 'HR';

ACCOUNT_STATUS                   LOCK_DAT EXPIRY_D
-------------------------------- -------- --------
OPEN                                      15.09.19

SQL> alter user hr identified by hr;

User altered.

SQL> connect hr/hr
Connected.
SQL>
```

Comment: I added a new image "sqlplus" output to the end of my post

Comment: OK, so how did you - previously - make HR appear again?

Comment: previously I was able to see HR on sqldeveloper not on sqlplus. And I still can see HR on sqldeveloper

Comment: Then you aren't connected to the same database in SQL*Plus and in SQL Developer.

Comment: is there any code to check whoami on sqlplus? or to check which database i am connected?

Comment: You specify it while connecting, by providing its alias (taken from the TNSNAMES.ORA) file, e.g. `connect hr/hr@xe`

Comment: To find database you're currently connected to, run `select sys_context('userenv', 'db_name') from dual;`

Comment: when I run the code it shows SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','DB_NAME')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
orcl

Comment: You should compare the result you got in both SQL Developer and SQL*Plus.

Comment: I guess, kind of know the problem now. but still don't know the solution. So from sql developer, I created two different connection to test about what you are saying, and both of them username sys as sysdba. But one of connection is Basic and the second one's connection is TNS. On sqldeveloper, I can see hr user, but not on the Basic connection

Comment: TNS allows you to use database's alias from the TNSNAMES.ORA file, so that you wouldn't have to type all those information - just as you have to do for the Basic connection (specifying host, port and SID). Basically, they should work just the same.

Comment: Okay, thank you, fixed the problem, really apreciate your help